# Mongo 2.6.x GridFS and java driver

Tags: java, mongodb, scala, gridfs

i can't write anymore to a GridFS mongo collection with the java driver, mongodb version is 2.6.8 (but i can reproduce the same issue on 2.4.6 as well) and driver is mongo-java-driver-2.12.1. I have a file-repository implementation which uses grid fs underneath and since today it fails to write to those collections with the following error :

`com.mongodb.MongoException: no md5 returned from server: { "serverUsed" : "127.0.0.1:27017" , "errmsg" : "exception: Can't get runner for query { files_id: ObjectId('55c2196fd4c6e731be2ba1e9'), n: { $gte: 0 } }" , "code" : 17241 , "ok" : 0.0}`

this is the output from my application with tracing and debug flags enabled in the driver.Does anyone know about this problem? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

for me this error occured because the gridfs collections lost an index. run this in mongo shell to fix it:

> use 
>   db.fs.files.ensureIndex({ filename : 1, uploadDate : 1})
>   db.fs.chunks.ensureIndex({ files_id : 1, n : 1 })